# Why does adding "|" to Set in Java flip the elements order?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set

I have two Lists and trying to form a String with element from each List, and in between when I do `" "`, the sorted order is maintained. But once I put `"|"` in the middle, which I would want to, the order of the elements in the Set gets switched around.

How can I add `"|"` and still maintain the sorted order in the Set `students`?

Here is the code:

```
   Set<String> students = new HashSet<>();
   Set<String> fn = new HashSet<>();
   Set<String> nums = new HashSet<>();

   List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>(fn);
   Collections.sort(firstNames);

   List<String> favNumbers = new ArrayList<>(nums);
   Collections.sort(favNumbers);

   for(int i=0; i<firstNames.size(); i++) {
       students.add(firstNames.get(i) + "|" + favNumbers.get(i));
   } 

   System.out.println(students);
```

With `... + " " + ...`, the order is `[Joshua 4, Lyon 7]`, but if `"|"` is added in place of `" "`, the order becomes `[Lyon|7, Joshua|4]` when I want and should be`[Joshua|4, Lyon|7]`.

Comment: I think a completely correct approach would be to have a student POJO along with a custom comparator which uses separate first and last name fields to sort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I just make a revision to my approach and make it work the way I want to?

Comment: Unlikely, but what would happen if, for some reason, a student had a pipe in his name?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Even more importantly, the students and their scores are sorted independently. If the scores are supposed to be matched with the corresponding students, your approach would fix that. Care to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I attempted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

A `HashSet` does not provide any ordering guarantees about its contents, using whatever ordering the underlying `HashMap` generates, which is in turn based on the `hashCode()` of the elements.

When you change the contents of a string, you get a different hash code--simple as that. The order in a `HashMap` is undefined and could change if you inserted additional elements triggering a rehash.

If you want a set with a guaranteed order, you can use a `SortedSet` implementation (such as `TreeSet`), but you'd need to write a proper class and implement suitable `Comparator`s. Alternately, you could use `LinkedHashSet`, which maintains elements in insertion order at the expense of additional overhead.

Comment: then instead of `HashSet<>();` for `students`, what should I use?

Comment: @JoKo You should have a `Student` class, not string pasting or parallel arrays.

Comment: I simply want to print in the order the elements were inserted in, so if Joshua|4 got added first, would like that to be the first element when printed, and creating a `Student` class seems like an overkill. Any simpler approach?

Comment: @JoKo Creating classes is *what you do* if you have data with any structure--just like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using object oriented design, as Java is an object oriented language.  Instead of trying to represent the various features of a student as independent collection, create a `Student` POJO which contains these features.  Then, create custom comparators to sort by either name or favorite number.

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int favNumber;

    // getters and setters

    public static Comparator<Student> NameComparator
                      = new Comparator<Student>() {

        public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
            String f1 = s1.getFirstName();
            String f2 = s2.getFirstName();
            String l1 = s1.getLastName();
            String l2 = s2.getLastName();
            if (l1.equalsIgnoreCase(l2) {
                return f1.toUpperCase().compareTo(f2);
            }
            else {
                return l1.toUpperCase().compareTo(l2);
            }
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Student> FavComparator
                      = new Comparator<Student>() {

        public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
            return s1.getFavNumber() < s2.getFavNumber();
        }
    };
}
```

Now if you have a list of students, `List<Student> list`, you can sort via:

```
Collections.sort(list, Student.NameComparator);
```

Or, to sort by favorite numbers, use:

```
Collections.sort(list, Student.FavComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So you cannot rely on `HashSet` to preserve any kind of order.

It looks to me like you just need to preserve the order of insertion, in which case you're better off not using a `Set` and rather a `List`, e.g.,

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
```